# How to change the JSON file contents for the below json file

Tags: python, json, shell

I have a json file say 1.control_file.txt and i need to chnage it's values every now and then,so say i have a ticket Sample1 and with that i need to change the date field, also other fields are required sometimes.
So suppose say i fetched the ticket no as user input and so how do i change the ticket field together with suppose say a given start and end date.
Also the exporter names tag in the json file should be changeable..
Can any on suggest me on how do i do that using shell or python?

Fields i am taking as user input user,ticket,startdate,end_date and sample_names...

````
 "user": "dexter",
 "ticket": "Sample1",
 "start_date": "2018-07-02",
 "end_date": "2019-07-02",
 "sample_names": [
    "Demo1exp1",
    "Demo2exp2",
    "Demo3exp3",
    "Demo4exp4",
    "Demo5exp5",
    "Demo6exp6",
    "Demo7exp7",
    "Demo8exp8",
    "Demo9exp9"
 ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code is probably what you need

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)

data['start_date'] = "2018-07-03" 

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```